# SQL Insert command not working in Python program

Tags: python-3.x, unix, pyodbc

I have a simple python program that loads a table in SQL server using an insert command.  It runs fine on my PC, which is using pyodbc version 4.0.0, but when it runs on a UNIX server that has pyodbc 4.0.26, the Insert command fails with a pyodbc error saying

> 'pyodbc.Error: ('07006',[07006][Openlink][ODBC][Driver]Restricted
> datatype attribute violation (0)(SQLBindparameter)').

Not sure why it fails with a newer version of pyodbc.  Before the Insert statement, I run a delete statement to clean out the table, and that works fine.  Any ideas?

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM [dbo].[Python_Table]")

f.write("deleted rows from Python Table")
f.write("\n====================\n")
db.commit()   
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Python_Table ([ID], [Compliant_Ind], [Mappings], [Govt_Req_1_Ind], [Govt_Req_2_Ind], [GLBA_Req_3_Ind],[GLBA_Req_4_Ind],[GLBA_Req_5_Ind], [Enterprise_Issue],  [Classification_Date], [Comments], [Load_Date]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)", row['ID'], row['Compliant_Ind'], row['Mappings'], row['Govt_Req_1_Ind'], row['Govt_Req_2_Ind'],row['Govt_Req_3_Ind'],row['Govt_Req_4_Ind'],row['Govt_Req_5_Ind'], row['Enterprise_Issue'], row['Classification_Date'], row['Comments'],row['load_date'])      

    db.commit()
```

Just the query, formatted to be easier to read:

```
"INSERT INTO dbo.Python_Table (
    [ID], 
    [Compliant_Ind], 
    [Mappings], 
    [Govt_Req_1_Ind], 
    [Govt_Req_2_Ind], 
    [GLBA_Req_3_Ind],
    [GLBA_Req_4_Ind],
    [GLBA_Req_5_Ind], 
    [Enterprise_Issue],  
    [Classification_Date], 
    [Comments], 
    [Load_Date]) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
    row['ID'], 
    row['Compliant_Ind'], 
    row['Mappings'], 
    row['Govt_Req_1_Ind'], 
    row['Govt_Req_2_Ind'],
    row['Govt_Req_3_Ind'],
    row['Govt_Req_4_Ind'],
    row['Govt_Req_5_Ind'], 
    row['Enterprise_Issue'], 
    row['Classification_Date'], 
    row['Comments'],
    row['load_date']
```

Comment: Without seeing code it will be hard to say.

Comment: @MarkRansom.  I have edited my post to now include a snapshot of the insert statement.  Hope this helps

Comment: It would be much better if it were text (formatted as code) rather than an image.  In particular you should strive for a [MCVE].

Comment: @MarkRansom  Image removed and replaced with text

Comment: Next problem, without knowing the contents of `row` it's impossible to see how the error is generated.

Comment: Only hint I saw after research is that this version of the driver does not handle data type conversions the same as the older one.  Make sure you initialise all your values and try to insert values of the proper type and format for each row.  A test you can do, print your query instead of running it, and try it directly on the database.  This will validate that at least the SQL is all ok before debugging your Python code.

Comment: `df.iterrows`, is that from a file?  Make sure your line terminations are ok for Unix (LF vs CRLF).  On linux you can use dos2unix, or `tr` to remove the Windows format line endings.

Comment: @Nic3500.  The SQL works fine when run on the database, and the python pgm wokrs fine when run on our pcs with pyodbc 4.0.0.  We created a new table with just one colum to test out two different types of insert statements.  The field is initialized first. This insert statement works:   
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PY_GLBA_Load_Log_Test2(File_Name) VALUES ('Test')").  

This insert statement gives us the error, but works fine using pyodbc 4.0.0 on our desktops:
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PY_GLBA_Load_Log_Test2(File_Name) VALUES (?)",'Test')

Comment: Looks like you will have to downgrade the version of the library until a final solution is found (or upgrade if a newer version exists.  It might be that version only).